# Time since timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Im trying to figure out the best way to find the amount of time since the `created_at` timestamp was placed on an article in my database. Id like it to be in minutes, then hours, then days.

I dont know where to really get started here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the `distance_of_time_in_words` helper for Rails which is kind of "vague" when it comes to times, so a friend and I re-wrote it into a gem called [`dotiw`](https://github.com/radar/dotiw) which would provide what you're after.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the examples listed and how they can help me in my case. Can you show me an example where I take a UTC time stamp auto generated and find out how much time has passes since then? Thanks.

Comment: `distance_of_time_in_words(thing.time, Time.now.utc)` will give an accurate to the second representation of the time that has passed since `thing.time`